# WP8 HTML5 app can't display image

Tags: html, web-services, windows-phone-8

I have a web service that returns an image when doing a HTTP GET and specifying a resource.  For example,

> http://www.[mydomain].com/api/v1/repository/image/test.jpg

will retrieve test.jpg and stream it to the browser.  The web service method that is invoked uses the following annotation...

```
@GET
@Path("/repository/image/{filename}")
@Produces("image/jpg")
```

Now this works just fine with IE10 and Chrome however in my Windows Phone 8 HTML5 app the image does not render. I simply get a placeholder indicating that the image could not be displayed.  Can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

UPDATE: Below is the web service code and associated html...

```
@GET
@Path("/repository/image/{filename}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("filename")String filename) 
   try {
        String path = "/tmp/" + filename;
        File imagefile = new File(path);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) imagefile);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
             "attachment; filename=" + id);
        return response.build();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
   }
}
```

I access the service in my HTML by simply setting the src attribute of the img tag as follows...

```
<img src='http://www.[mydomain].com/api/v1/repository/image/test.jpg'/>
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the url ?

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced a similar problem. It was opening in IE10 desktop but not on the phone. It turned out the format of the image provided to me wasn't right. I used preview (Mac app) to open and save the image again in a different name and now that image works fine. You can use any image editor app not only preview to save the image.

The supported image formats of Windows Phone can be seen here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ImageSupport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ImageSupport)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly sounds like an image format issue.

Does the web service always return a jpeg?
If so, for JPEGs, I'd make sure the provided image was saved in RGB Colour and not CMYK Colour mode.

I've experienced the same issue on WP8, but only for some PNG images. The provided PNG images would display fine in all other browsers, but would show as a broken image on WP8.
Turns out the provided PNG images was not flattened (i.e. it contained the generating application's layering information etc.).